"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after calling New
Public Class Form1
    Dim Form2 As Form2
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With Me.Form2
            Me.Form2 = New Form2("Some name")
            .TopLevel = False
        End With
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Public Property AAAName As String
    Sub New(NameInput As String)
        Me.AAAName = NameInput
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class

When I run the code (Starts with Form1), I get error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object



Try initialize Form2 before the With block like this:
Public Class Form1
Dim Form2 As Form2

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Form2 = New Form2("Form name")
    
    With Me.Form2
        .TopLevel = False
    End With

    Me.Controls.Add(Form2)
    Form2.Show()
  End Sub
End Class



Public Class Form2
Public Property AAAName As String

Sub New(NameInput As String)
    Me.AAAName = NameInput
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  End Sub
End Class


This is the right answer. Thank You!

If only one property is assigned in the With-statement, the With-statement can be removed and the assignment can be simplified: Form2.TopLevel = False. Note also that Me. only necessary to disambiguate and can be removed when this is not required: Controls.Add(Form2)
